# How can I prepend filenames with ascending numbers like 1_ 2_?

Tags: command-line, bash, batch-rename

How can I add numbers to the files in one directory?

In one directory I have files like below:

```
fileA
fileB
fileC
fileD
```

I want to prepend ascending numbers to them, like this:

```
1_fileA
2_fileB
3_fileC
4_fileD
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @PerlDuck Yes, I have to enumarte them changing their name.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/839959

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One of the solutions:

`cd <your dir>` then run in bash (copy and paste in command-line):

```
n=1; for f in *; do mv "$f" "$((n++))_$f"; done
```

Bash script case:

```
#!/bin/bash
n=1
for f in *
do
  if [ "$f" = "rename.sh" ]
  then
    continue
  fi
  mv "$f" "$((n++))_$f"
done
```

save it as `rename.sh` to dir with files to rename, `chmod +x rename.sh` then run it `./rename.sh`

Comment: but can I also run this from vim? I mean to put your code in vim as #!/bin/bash and the run it from the command line?

Comment: Sure. But you need add this simple command to bash file. Then You need to solve self-renaming of this rename.sh file.

Comment: Added example with bash file. If you need something like bash command to run it in any file system place, you need use first example saved in bash file and add this bash file to PATH with alias.

Answer (score 12):

1. Open your directory in Nautilus.
2. Highlight all of the files.
3. Right-click, and select "Rename..." from the context menu.
4. On the Rename dialog, click the <kbd>+Add</kbd> button.
5. Select "1,2,3,4" under "Automatic Numbers"
6. Then, in the Rename dialog, in the text entry field, insert an
   underscore "_" character between "[1, 2, 3]" and "[Original file name]".

   It should look like "[1, 2, 3]_[Original file name]"
7. Click the <kbd>Rename</kbd> button.

[image: Select "1,2,3,4" in the Rename dialog]

[image: The renamed files]

Answer (score 9):

If there are more than 9 files, I would use `printf` to pad the number to get the expected sort order, like this

```
n=0
for f in *
    do printf -v new "%2d$((++n))_$f"
    echo mv -v -- "$f" "$new"
done
```

Remove `echo` when you see the correct result.

#### Explanation

In this line, `do printf -v new "%2d$((++n))_$f"` we create a format for the new filenames and put it into the variable `new`.

`%2d` is a 2 digit decimal number. Instead of `2d`, you can use `3d` etc to get another leading 0 (if you have more than 99 files).

`((++n))` increments the variable `n` (which we set to 0 at the start of the script). Since it is iterated once each time the loop is run, files get incremented name prefixes.

`-v` makes `mv` print what will be changed.

`--` in the `mv` statement is to prevent filenames that start with `-` being interpreted as options.

Answer (score 7):

That’s a job for [`file-rename` [image: Install file-rename]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/rename) (aka perl rename or just `rename`):

```bsh
file-rename -n 'our $i; if (!$i) {$i++}; s/^/sprintf("%d_", $i++)/e' *
```

This defines a variable, increases it if it’s not set (else it would start with `0` instead of `1`) and replaces the beginning of the filename with the number increasing it every time. You can change the format easily, e.g. to make it three-digit (`001`, `002`, …) use `"%03d_"`. Running it with `-n` only prints the changes, to actually perform the renaming remove this flag.

#### Example run

Using the alternatives system, `rename` is linked to `file-rename` on my system.

```bsh
$ ls -1
fileA
fileB
fileC
fileD
$ rename -n 'our $i; if (!$i) {$i++}; s/^/sprintf("%d_", $i++)/e' *
rename(fileA, 1_fileA)
rename(fileB, 2_fileB)
rename(fileC, 3_fileC)
rename(fileD, 4_fileD)
$ rename 'our $i; if (!$i) {$i++}; s/^/sprintf("%d_", $i++)/e' *
$ ls -1
1_fileA
2_fileB
3_fileC
4_fileD
```

Comment: err, you still use `rename` in ”Example run“ ... ;)

Answer (score 2):

One option is

```
cd /path/to/folder/
ls -1v | rename -n -v 's/^/sprintf("%02d_", ++our$i)/e'
```

- This works fine, except with the file names with new line "\n". Switch '-1v'takes care of spaces and tabs,
- Other commands posted here change the order of files with numbers e.g. 10a comes before 1a.
- Whichever suits in a situation.

I had some time to test all these commands. Here are the results.

```
$ ls
001abc.txt  '10a bc.txt'   1abc.txt  '2ab c.txt'  'a'$'\t''bc.txt'

$ ls -1v | rename -n -v 's/^/sprintf("%02d_", ++our$i)/e'
Reading filenames from file handle (GLOB(0x55cb57991b28))
rename(001abc.txt, 01_001abc.txt)
rename(1abc.txt, 02_1abc.txt)
rename(2ab c.txt, 03_2ab c.txt)
rename(10a bc.txt, 04_10a bc.txt)
rename(a    bc.txt, 05_a    bc.txt)

$ n=1; for f in *; do echo mv "$f" "$((n++))_$f"; done
mv 001abc.txt 1_001abc.txt
mv 10a bc.txt 2_10a bc.txt
mv 1abc.txt 3_1abc.txt
mv 2ab c.txt 4_2ab c.txt
mv a    bc.txt 5_a  bc.txt

$ for f in *;     do printf -v new "%2d$((++n))_$f";     echo mv -v -- "$f" "$new"; done
mv -v -- 001abc.txt  09_001abc.txt
mv -v -- 10a bc.txt  010_10a bc.txt
mv -v -- 1abc.txt  011_1abc.txt
mv -v -- 2ab c.txt  012_2ab c.txt
mv -v -- a  bc.txt  013_a   bc.txt

$ ./rename.sh 
mv 001abc.txt 1_001abc.txt
mv 10a bc.txt 2_10a bc.txt
mv 1abc.txt 3_1abc.txt
mv 2ab c.txt 4_2ab c.txt
mv a    bc.txt 5_a  bc.txt

$ rename -n 'our $i; if (!$i) {$i++}; s/^/sprintf("%d_", $i++)/e' *
rename(001abc.txt, 1_001abc.txt)
rename(10a bc.txt, 2_10a bc.txt)
rename(1abc.txt, 3_1abc.txt)
rename(2ab c.txt, 4_2ab c.txt)
rename(a    bc.txt, 5_a bc.txt)
rename(rename.sh, 6_rename.sh)

$ for f in *;     do printf -v new "%2d$((++n))_$f";     echo mv -v -- "$f" "$new"; done
mv -v -- 001abc.txt  01_001abc.txt
mv -v -- 10a bc.txt  02_10a bc.txt
mv -v -- 1abc.txt  03_1abc.txt
mv -v -- 2ab c.txt  04_2ab c.txt
mv -v -- a  bc.txt  05_a    bc.txt
mv -v -- rename.sh  06_rename.sh
```

Comment: being able to handle filenames with whitespace ie. newlines, tabs and spaces is a big ++

Answer (score 0):

An additional way with Python's rename tool (replace the `print` with `os.rename` to actually perform the task if the results look correct)

```bsh
$ cd "/your/file/path" && python -c "\
import os; \
[print('{0}_{1}'.format(i, f)) \\
    for i, f in enumerate(filter(lambda x: not os.path.isdir(x), os.listdir('.')), 1)]"

1_fileA
2_fileB
3_fileC
4_fileD
...
26_fileZ

# to rename, replace the print line with
[os.rename(f, '{0}_{1}'.format(i, f)) \\
```

It first looks through a list of the files in the location result from the `cd` command. `os.listdir('.')`

Removes any directories from the that list `filter(lambda x: not os.path.isdir(x), os.listdir('.'))`

Then the resulting filenames are traversed, along with a counter to append to the new name `for i, f in enumerate(..., 1)`. Here `f` is the file's name and `i` is the counter. The counter is set to start at 1 instead of 0.

In the format string, `'{0}_{1}'.format(i, f)`, `{0}` is the first given variable, the counter, and `{1}` is the file's name separated with the '_' character.

Some padding can be given to the numbers like in some of the other answers.

```bsh
$ cd "/your/file/path" && python -c "\
import os; \
pad = len(str(len(os.listdir('.')))); \
[print('{0:0{2}d}_{1}'.format(i, f, pad)) \\
    for i, f in enumerate(filter(lambda x: not os.path.isdir(x), os.listdir('.')), 1)]"

01_fileA
02_fileB
...
26_fileZ

# to rename, replace the print line with
[os.rename(f, '{0:0{2}d}_{1}'.format(i, f, pad)) \\
```

`{2}` is the third given variable, in this case the padding which is set to the the length (number of digits) of the number of files in the directory. If there are 23 files, pad = 2. If there are 101 files, pad = 3. 45678, padding = 5, etc.