# Renaming muliple files at once

Tags: command-line, rename

I have a bunch of wav files I converted to mp3 files using ffmpeg.

Now the mp3 files are all named `file.wav.mp3`.

How can I remove the `.wav` suffix while keeping the rest of the file name?
I would like to do this on a whole directory at once.

Comment: you'll need a script or a small C program to do this. any experience in system programming ?

Comment: @GiorgosSaridakis: What's wrong with `mmv` or `rename`
?

Comment: @JörgWMittag mmv is super, I didn't know it existed

Comment: What is your ffmpeg command in the first place?

Comment: Hint - it's the same as https://askubuntu.com/questions/839959/bulk-rename-files and probably quite a few other questions in the SE network.

Comment: Also worth noting that nautilus supports batch renaming.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I easily rename multiple files using command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58546/how-do-i-easily-rename-multiple-files-using-command-line)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With a shell loop, removing the shortest "double dot suffix"

```
for f in *.wav.mp3; do echo mv "$f" "${f%.*.*}.mp3"; done
```

or (my personal favorite for things like this) with `mmv` from package `mmv`

```
mmv -n '*.wav.mp3' '#1.mp3'
```

Remove the `echo` or the `-n` as appropriate once you are happy that they are doing the right thing.

Comment: thanks, i like the mmv option.  really simple

Comment: If you are using `zsh`, `zmv` is also great.

Comment: I always recommend using `mv -n` or `-i` for bulk/automated renames like this, to avoid the possibility of silently & irreversibly deleting files if there's a name conflict.

Answer (score 19):

Read [`man rename`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/file-rename.1p.html) and do something like:

```bsh
rename 's/.wav.mp3/.mp3/' *.wav.mp3
```

You may have to `sudo apt install rename`, first.

Comment: For this to work, you should install the `rename` package first. It is not installed by default.

Comment: ... perhaps `s/\.wav\.mp3$/.mp3/` to err on the safe side...?

Comment: I included an example in my answer. Didn't that help?

Comment: I recommend always running `rename` with the `-n` option first to see what it will do, then removing `-n` once one is satisfied.

Answer (score 7):

In the file browser in Ubuntu, you can select multiple files and rename them according to a pattern by just hitting <kbd>F2</kbd> or right-clicking and selecting *Rename*.

Here I am replacing `x` with `_by_`. In  your case you can replace `.wav` with an empty string.

[image: rename multiple files in Ubuntu]

Comment: Thanks Mr Felix U for this tip. I have been using RANGER for this operation for a long time. But this is much simpler.

Answer (score 4):

As you can see there are multiple ways to achieve this. Another way using the basename command is shown below:

```
for file in ./*.wav.mp3
do
    mv "$file" "$(basename "$file" .wav.mp3)".mp3 
done
```

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you for pointing to this nice article. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: I added quotes around the command substitution as well - remember, if `$file` contains whitespace, then `basename "$file" .wav.mp3` will as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you have all the files named in `.wav.mp3` format, then use the following command:

```
for i in *.wav.mp3; do echo $i; mv "$i" "${i::-8}.mp3"; done
```

Comment: String manipulation takes negative values so `"${i::-8}.mp3"` should generate same result. Better to quote the whole string than to concat the strings

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have edited it.

Answer (score 1):

When in the directory with the `.wav.mp3` files:

```
for i in *.wav.mp3; do mv "$i" "$(echo $i | sed s/.wav//g)"; done
```

That said, you may be able to use the same for your ffmpeg command so you don't have to rename them later.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add a tool tip:

A real nice program for such tasks is [emv](http://www.i0i0.de/toolchest/emv).

You run it as `emv *.wav.mp3* and it opens an editor. You can then use search & replace. Then you save the file and close the editor and the program renames your files.

This is especially handy, when you know how to use an advanced editor like `vim`, but even when most simple editors support search & replace, what is what you usually need for problems like yours.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *
do
 #Define the string value
 text="$i"

 # Set .wav as the delimiter
 IFS='.wav.'

 #Read the split words into an array based on space delimiter
read -a strarr <<< "$text"
mv "$i" "${strarr[0]).mp3" #changing input file name


done
```