# How to rename multiple file at once

Tags: command-line, bash

Given that i have folder that contain 170+ files that were named like `'SM-RVT70UQTNWC02.png'$'\r'`
how can I fast change this to `SM-RVT70UQTNWC02.png`? I have tried to apply solution from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263083/renaming-muliple-files-at-once) however i'm struggling how to make my regex `'*(.*)'\$'\\r'` work with `rename` as I get many errors like:

```
Scalar found where operator expected at (eval 8) line 1, near "*)$\"
        (Missing operator before $\?)
Backslash found where operator expected at (eval 8) line 1, near "$\\"
        (Missing operator before \?)
syntax error at (user-supplied code), near "*)$\"
```

Comment: I believe you should put the `$` first `$'s/(.*)\r$/$1/'` the second is just for matching line end

Comment: due to the number of files, you can use `rename` in combination with find: `find . -type f -print0 | rename -0 -d $'s/(.*)\r$/$1/'`

Comment: It worked. I still don't understand what happen there, but it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you listed the file with `ls`, the quotes are not part of the file name,
they are used to help understanding weird file names. The file in question is the concatenation
of `SM-RVT70UQTNWC02.png` and a carriage return (the byte 0x0D), which in Bash can be represented
by `$'\r'` (see [ANSI quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html)).

To remove the trailing carriage return character of the `.png` files in
the current directory,

```
rename 's/\r$//' *.png?
```

The syntax means: **s**ubstitute the carriage return **`\r`** at the end of the line **`$`** by nothing.

A POSIX compliant alternative would be

```
for f in *.png"$(printf '\r')"; do mv -- "$f" "${f%?}"; done
```

Printf is the portable way to specify a carriage return, and [`${f%?}`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) removes the last character of the file name.

Answer (score 1):

In that folder run:

```bsh
for i in *.png*; do
    mv -i "${i}" "${i%.png*}.png"
done
```

as a one-liner, this becomes

```bsh
for i in *.png*; do mv -i "${i}" "${i%.png*}.png"; done
```

This loops over all the files matching `*.png*` in the current directory and renames (moves) them by cutting off everything starting at the *last* occurence of `.png` and then appending `.png` again. Using `%%` instead would start cutting off from the first occurence of `.png`. You can drop the `-i` if you don't want to confirm overwriting existing files.

Comment: A more selective solution would be `for i in *.png?; do mv -i "${i}" "${i%?}"; done`, althought it would still rename non carriage return files (e.g. `a.pngx` to `a.png`).