# Create a script to rename a file, by first creating a filename using custom parameters from terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Lets consider that the output of my every custom execution (some software in linux), gets saved in a generic filename /mydump/xyz.out. Instead of custom naming every output file, I want to write a script which does the following:-

1. navigates to /mydump  (cd mydump)
2. creates a filename using arguments passed eg. config1_config2xconfig3.out
3. renames xyz.out to config1_config2xconfig3.out (mv xyz.out "configbasedfilename")

For this what I understand is I should create some function in a script file, eg. custom_rename () and call it with config1-2-3 from the terminal whenever I wish to rename.

eg:- $custom_rename config1 config2 config3
or
$ ./custom_rename.csh config1 config2 config3

or whatever makes sense.

Comment: Yes that's right, but I struggle to understand what your actual question is.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  I agree with @AndrewRichards here -- It's unclear given the way your post is worded exactly what question you have.  Are you looking for assistance with a script?  Simply validation that you are on the right track?  The best way to do it?  (Note, "best way" is off-topic as "Subjective"/"Opinion-based", though).  Please edit your post to clarify your question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own, probably limited script. Why not use "Bulk-rename" or similar packages, that are readily available?

[[image: 1]]

There are [more tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/839959/bulk-rename-files) available. I wouldn't write anything myself...